# How to reset the slider input when it completes its task in shiny context

Tags: r, animation, shiny, slider

As shown in the image below, I have a slider input that is animated by clicking the play button. It works perfectly except it does not get back to the starting point (here year=2010) when it reaches out to the maximum point (here year=2050). Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks,

Nader

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("v1", "Slider1:", min = 1, max = 5,value = 1,animate = TRUE)
)

server=function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$v1,{
        if(input$v1 == 5){
            updateSliderInput(session,'v1',value = 1)  
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! A follow-up question: how can reset the slider when a new county is selected? Please see the image for more info.